Control user level data visibility in reports
I have created an opportunity report from admin(admin able to view all the opportunity records) and place the report on a folder and provided view access to sales rep.
when a sales rep runs the report, requirement is, that particular sales rep should view only his respective owned records as in UI, but he is able to see all the records that is owned by others also.
How to restrict this user to view only owned records on this custom report.

If a user can see the record in the UI, they can see it in a report. There are some filters you may try using, such as Owner filter being set to "My Team", which should work if the organizational role hierarchy is configured correctly.
